# MS Access runtime 2448: Cannont assign value, but works when I try again

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got this code within MS Access data entry form:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

    Dim POCode As String ' kód objednávky pro daného dodavatele (např. ROT, MTE...)
    
    ' zjištění kódu dodavatele
    POCode = DLookup("POCode", "dbo_tbl1Suppliers", "SupplierID=" & Me!cboSupplierID)

    ' Pokud zadávám novou objednávku, tak vyplnit označení objednávky (2022ROT001)
    If IsNull(Me.PurchaseOrderCode) Then
        Me.PurchaseOrderCode = Year(Date) & POCode & Format(DCount("*", "dbo_tbl1PurchaseOrders", "PurchaseOrderCode Like ""%" & Year(Date) & POCode & "%""") + 1, "000")
    End If

    ' Zavřít formulář a aktualizovat související formuláře
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmDEPurchaseOrder", acSaveYes
    RequeryForm ("frmPurchaseOrderDetails")
    RequeryForm ("frmPurchaseOrderList")

End Sub
```

When I'm creating/editing a Purchase Order and I click the SAVE button, it should automatically fill in the PurchaseOrderCode (containing current year, supplier code and a subsequent number - for example 2022ROT010 - 10th order this is for supplier "ROT").

When I press the SAVE button while creating a new PO, I get **MS Access runtime 2448: Cannont assign value**. However, when I press SAVE again, everything works fine.

This is happening on the line where I'm assigning value to **Me.PurchaseOrderCode**

Does anyone know why that might be happening? thanks.

Comment: Has a new record actually been created in the form when you click that button?

Comment: Actually the record is saved the moment I click into the subform. When I press SAVE, I get the error and the Order Code isn't saved. But when I simply click SAVE again, it works.